# Toeplitz matrix function in R

Tags: r

I'm interested in creating a function in R, using for-loops, that returns a toeplitz matrix. The argument should be a vector with an uneven number of elements. Any ideas?

[image: Examples of toeplitz matrices]

Comment: How about using the base function, `stats::toeplitz`?

Comment: Please specify the input and the output, not just the output.